# inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command

Tags: angular

When i run `ng -v` in my machine, I have:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.16
node: 4.6.0
os: win32 x64
```

I have tried to add:

```
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.16"
```

In the dependencies of project and then `npm install`, but my node fails to install the package.

Comment: Yes I First update angular CLI to make sure it is the most recent version.

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
Next install all dependencies by executing npm install or npm i from the directory  downloaded the package to. This downloads and installs all the dependencies mentioned in the package.json file and their dependencies.

Then run the development build by using the npm start command. This will transpile the typescript and creates a webpack that can be accessed using the url given in the console (http://localhost:3000). I also try to use the ng serve command again & it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems "angular-cli" was the old name when angular cli package was still in beta stage. The new angular cli is called "@angular/cli".

Picture from libraries.io
[image]

The renamed angular cli package, @angular/cli's first version coincides with angular-cli's last version:
[image]

The package you were trying to install does not exist in npm anymore. The version you were trying to install also does not exist in the renamed @angular/cli package. You should run `npm i @angular/cli@latest` to get the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

---

I First update angular CLI to make sure it is the most recent version. npm install -g @angular/cli@latest Next install all dependencies by executing npm install or npm i from the directory downloaded the package to. This downloads and installs all the dependencies mentioned in the package.json file and their dependencies. Then run the development build by using the npm start command. This will transpile the typescript and creates a webpack that can be accessed using the url given in the console (localhost:3000). I also try to use the ng serve command again & it works.